# Get foreach() loop to display array output in given manner

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

**SQL:**

```
SELECT uFName, uLName, listTitle, listPropPrice, listCmt, listDt, mFName, mLName, moAmt, moDtOff
FROM User U, Listing L, Merchant M, MerchantOffer MO
WHERE U.uID = L.uID
and L.listID = MO.listID
and M.mID = MO.mId
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php 
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    print_r($result); //or var_dump($result); for more info
    foreach($result as $row){
        print_r($row);
    }   
    ?>
```

**Kolinks output:**

[image]

Why is it duplicating everything twice??

Comment: Do you know what `echo` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$half = array_splice($row,0,5);
echo implode(" ",$half)."<br /><br />Merchant Offered:<br />".implode(" ",$row);
```

Basically it extracts the first five values and concatenates them with space, then puts in the "Merchant Offered" text, then concatenates the remaining values.

Comment: this works, but it duplicates the fields twice. Why is that?? How do I fix that?

Comment: Please see **Kolinks output:**

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what you mean by your comment. Could you explain further what's happening?

Comment: Use fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) or fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM) or any other fetch type, depending on your needs, see http://php.net/pdostatement.fetch

Comment: Oh yeah. Cuz `fetchAll` alone gets all the values in an associative array, AND as an indexed array, so all the values are there twice. Well spotted, @johannes.

Comment: THANK YOU BOTH!!!!!!! Outstanding help! Wish I had enough rep to +1 this. Thanks guys!